# Azure Mobile Services client Authentication not working. Keep getting "Exception Unhandeld"

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am Working on Xamarin.Froms (PCL) project. I am working with Azure Mobile Services to add Login Authentication to my Test App. But I keep getting an Unhandled Exception. Every Time I run this line of Code 
`user = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(this, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook, Constants.ApplicationURL);`
This Code snippet is from my "{myApp}.Droid" MainActivity.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
public class MainActivity : FormsApplicationActivity, IAuthenticate
{

    private MobileServiceUser user;


    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Initialize Azure Mobile Apps
        CurrentPlatform.Init();

        // Initialize Xamarin Forms
        Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        // Initialize login provider

        App.Init((IAuthenticate)this);


        // Load the main application
        LoadApplication (new App ());

    }
    public async Task<bool> Authenticate()
    {

        var success = false;
        var message = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            //var token = new JObject { { "access_token", "access_token_value" } };

            user = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(this, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook, Constants.ApplicationURL);

            if (user != null)
            {
                message = string.Format("You are now signed in as {0}.", user.UserId);
                success = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = ex.Message;
        }
        // Display success or failure message 
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.SetMessage(message);
        builder.SetTitle("Sign-in Result");
        builder.Create().Show();

        return success;
    }
}`
```

MyApp Runs but the Facebook Authentication Page does not show up. as my app crashes Every time I run the app.

Here is the link to MSDN File I am trying to replicate [Adding Authentication to Azure Mobile Clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-users#a-nameadd-authenticationaadd-authentication-to-the-app)

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the link to MSDN File I am trying to replicate [Adding Authentication to Azure Mobile Clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-users#a-nameadd-authenticationaadd-authentication-to-the-app).

I noticed that the link you provided is about adding authentication to your **Xamarin.Android** app. For adding authentication to the Android app project of your Xamarin.Forms, you could refer to [Add authentication to the portable class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users#add-authentication-to-the-portable-class-library) and [Add authentication to the Android app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users#add-authentication-to-the-android-app).

**Sign in with Facebook login using the server-managed flow:**

```
MobileServiceUser user = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(this,
   MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
```

Additionally, you could debug and collect crash report to narrow this issue. Here is a document about [Debugging and Error Tracking](https://xamarinhelp.com/debugging-and-error-tracking-day-13/), you could refer to it.

**UPDATE:**

For using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 4.0.1, I followed [Add your app to the Allowed External Redirect URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users#add-authentication-to-the-android-app) and add `bruceapp://easyauth.callback` as Allowed External Redirect URLs on Azure Portal.

Then, use the following code for login operation:

```
user = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount, "bruceapp");
```

I checked with my bruce_mobile.UWP project, the login operation could work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for answering Bruce! I have tried the other msdn link aswell. But the problem i get using that is the link is outdated. The LoginAsync(..) method parameters shown above do not work. I am currently using "Mobile Service Client 4.0.1" I have to add an additional parameter of URI shceme. But I still get the Unhandled exception everytime code runs the "loginAsync" line

Comment: I used Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 3.1.0 with my app, it could work as expected. I would check the newer version tomorrow, you could use 3.1.0  to narrow this issue.

Comment: I updated my answer for using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 4.0.1, you could refer to it. Additionally, have you solved this issue?